# DueDate (delivery time) issue - transfer DateTime object between two Web App via REST API

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm working with a system that integrates two web applications. In the first web application, sellers create orders for stores. The second web application is used by the stores themselves to fulfill orders created for them and make deliveries. The integration system between these two applications makes a REST API call to the first application to retrieve data on the created order, including the delivery time. Then this data is processed in the integration application and transferred to a second web application, also via REST API, to create an order for a specific store.
The problem arose when comparing the display of delivery time on the websites of these applications.
The first application in which the order is placed does not know in which time zone the store that must fulfill this order may be located. Therefore, the first application passes the delivery time as a DateTime object with type `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`. Previously, in the integration application there was no conversion of this DateTime value and the second application accepted this value as is.
Let's assume that the *1/05/2024 **7:35PM*** Datetime object is created in the first WebApp. This datetime can be seen the same on the WebApp1 UI, regardless of the user’s timezone. I (UTC+02) and the QA (UTC+01) see delivery date the same way as *1/05/2024 **7:35PM***.
On the store website we see this time differently. I see *1/05/2024 **9:35PM*** and QA see *1/05/2024 **8:35PM***. However, this order was created for a store located in the EST time zone (UTC-05) and the store employee opened this order (WebApp2) should see the same date that is displayed for the WebApp1  - *1/05/2024 **7:35PM***. So if I was in the EST timezone I would see the delivery time on WebApp2 UI as *1/05/2024 **2:35PM***, which is incorrect.
So my task, as I see it, is this:

1. Find the timezone in which the specific store where the order will be fulfilled is located
2. Set the original DateTime object received from the WebApp1 API to have a time offset relative to UTC, taking into account the previously found store timezone
3. Convert the received DateTime object in the second paragraph to UTC format to put it in the WebApp2 API request

The implementation looks like this:

```
string storeTimeZone = _dbService.GetStoreTimezone(storeNumber);
TimeSpan utcOffset = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(storeTimeZone)
    .GetUtcOffset(order.DueDate); //order.DueDate has DateTime value from WebApp1 with DateTimeKind.Unspecified
DateTime dueDateUtc = DateTime.SpecifyKind(new DateTimeOffset(order.DueDate, utcOffset).ToUniversalTime().DateTime, DateTimeKind.Utc);
...
request.Order.DueDate = dueDateUtc;
```

It really confuses me that the code that creates a new DateTime object looks somehow complicated and ugly. Isn't there an easier way to get the DateTime object I need?